# Why do the Minions remain loyal to Gru after he is no longer a villain?

Tags: despicable-me, minions

From the description of [Minions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minions_%28film%29):

> Minions are small, yellow creatures who have existed since the beginning of time, evolving from single-celled organisms into beings who exist only to serve history's most despicable masters.

Yet, by the end of Despicable Me, Gru has left his villainous, despicable ways behind and even becomes a hero for the AVL in Despicable Me 2 and 3.

However, the Minions never show anything but unwavering loyalty for Gru and never seek out another master after Gru becomes a good guy.

Why do the Minions remain loyal to Gru after is no longer despicable?

The simplest explanation might be that Gru treated them better than their other masters, nor did they ever accidently kill Gru. Is that supported by any supplementary materials or is there a better explanation?

Comment: *"unwavering loyalty for Gru*" - There you go

Comment: There's action and fun, I think that's all they ever really needed to be honest.

Comment: Scariest movie franchise evar. I mean... GIANT. ANIMATED. TWINKIES.

Comment: Although their origin was retconned, the minions were originally conceived as genetically modified corn that Gru had (presumably) created.

Comment: This strikes me as a false premise.  Minions seem to be attracted to who has power not who is despicable - though those may be highly correlated.

Comment: Dr. Nefario also has a (more nuanced) conflict on this area.

Comment: @Tronman   I could suggest that possibly the Minions both have higher ethical standards than most people and are also loyal to evil persons.  So most people might think that once Grue becomes no worse than most people, he has has become good. But maby the Minions know that by becomeing no worse than most people Gru has barely started to turn good and so is still evil enough to for them to obey.  But I doubt that the creators of Dispicable Me have such an opinion of the ethics of most people.t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the *[Despicable Me 2: The Official Minion Manual](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20634195-the-official-minion-manual)*, the Minions love Gru not because he's a villain, but because he's nice to them and treats them with care and respect, in turn engendering their undying loyalty.

> The Minions are Gru’s henchmen.
> **They do whatever Gru needs
> them to do.
> Gru is their hero. When Gru
> is happy, the Minions are
> happy. When Gru is sad,
> the Minions are sad.**
> Gru used to be a super villain,
> but now he’s a dad. That
> means the Minions used to
> make explosives, but now they
> make jelly. They used to help
> steal famous landmarks. Now
> they babysit.

> **Q. Whom do the Minions respect above everyone else?
>
> A. Gru**

Comment: Perfect. Nice find.